# Is use in an unused default member initializer still an odr-use?

Tags: c++, one-definition-rule, template-instantiation, implicit-instantiation

Is use in a default member initializer still an odr-use, even if the default member initializer is not used by any constructor?

For example, is this program ill-formed because `g<A>` is odr-used and therefore its definition implicitly instantiated?

```
template<typename T>
void g() { sizeof(T); }

struct A;

struct B {
    B() : i{} {};

    int i = (&g<A>, 0);
};

int main() { }
```

MSVC thinks no. Clang, GCC and ICC think yes. https://godbolt.org/z/zrr9oEdfe

Comment: `g<A>` is [potentially-evaluated](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#3), and it does not fall into any of the exceptions listed in the [definition of odr-use](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#5). Therefore it is odr-used. All compilers are behaving correctly, even MSVC, because odr violations are classified as "[no diagnostic required](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.def.odr#11)".

Comment: @RaymondChen There is a reachable definition for `g<A>` which I think should be implicitly instantiated if the function is odr-used. That instantiation would be ill-formed, so I thought a diagnostic should be given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71408718/is-use-in-an-unused-default-member-initializer-still-an-odr-use#comment126293425_71408718) in the comments, `g<A>` is odr-used.  However, there *is* a definition for it available, so there is no non-diagnosable violation here; MSVC is **wrong** to accept it.  (This is true even without the constructor declaration; the implicitly declared `B::B()` is never defined, but the default member initializer is still an odr-use like it is here.)