# Does a consteval function odr-use a global variable if it takes its address?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Look at this snippet:

```
struct Foo {
    int a, b;
};
extern Foo f;

consteval bool fn() {
    return &f.a < &f.b;
}

int main() {
    return fn();
}
```

Suppose that this is the whole program (no other translation units), `f` has no definition available (it's only `extern` declared). But `fn` takes the address of a subobject of `f`. Of course, the compiler can evaluate `&f.a < &f.b` without the definition. But I'm not sure what the standard says about this case. Does `&f.a < &f.b` odr-use `f`? [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) says that

> Informally, an object is odr-used if its value is read (unless it is a compile time constant) or written, **its address is taken**

I tried to interpret the "Formally" part which is described afterwards (and I also checked the current [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#5) about this), but I couldn't draw a confident conclusion.

It would make sense that in this case `f` is not odr-used (because it's not really needed to evaluate the expression), but the "**its address is taken**" at cppreference may mean that `f` **is** odr-used.

Comment: "*Suppose that this is the whole program*" Then you have a compile error because `fn` is not called during constant evaluation. And even if you stick a `constexpr auto var = fn();` in main, you'll just get a different compile error: attempting to access a non-constant expression from within constant evaluation.

Comment: @NicolBolas, hmm, both gcc and clang compiles it: https://godbolt.org/z/rGrfo7xTs

Comment: It is unambiguous that `f.a` and `f.b` have their addresses taken, so they are odr-used. Full stop. What I'm not 100% certain is the consequences of odr-usage occuring in `consteval` context.

Comment: @NicolBolas: `fn()` is a constant expression, so there’s no error there.  The call doesn’t have to be part of something marked `constexpr`.  Moreover, `&f.…` is a constant expression, so there’s no problem there either.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any exception from the odr-use definition that would apply here.

There is an id-expression naming `f` and it is potentially-evaluated. So the base requirements of [[basic.def.odr]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.def.odr#4) for odr-use are met. There are a few exceptions listed there:

(4.1) is an exception for only reference type variables.

(4.2) applies only to variables that are *usable in constant expressions*, which doesn't apply here because `f` is neither a `const` integral/enumerations type, nor `constexpr`. See [[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.const).

(4.3) is specific to discarded-value expressions.

None of these exceptions apply, so `f` is odr-used and consequently a definition must exist.

---

I think there are multiple places where the odr-use rule is stricter than would intuitively be necessary. I asked a similar question about default member initializers which aren't actually used by any constructor and the answer there also was that a variable/function used in it is odr-used even if there is no way of it ever being evaluated. See [Is use in an unused default member initializer still an odr-use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71408718/is-use-in-an-unused-default-member-initializer-still-an-odr-use).